# Placeholder for switching between GUI's

Tags: c#, user-interface, placeholder

I have a C# main form where I have the buttons of my functionalities:

[image]

Example: I have opened my 'Manage companies'-form but want to open it inside the main form itself.

I want to do this for all of my other functionalities.

Is there some kind of placeholder or something else that I could use without having to change too much of my existing GUI's?

Thanks

Comment: WPF? WinForms? WinRT? What framework do you use?

Comment: i use devexpress for my GUI's so I guess WinForms

Comment: You guess? Meaning, you don't know? devexpress also has a suite for wpf.. Get one of the forms and check its base class and paste here a full name with namespaces. That will answer all about the framework. Oh, and the version of devx could be needed as well if someone tries to answer.

Comment: Re the problem, if that's winforms, then at base level any container (Form, etc) where you can put your controls can host another controls defined elsewhere (but cannot host other Forms directly). It's all matter of assigning Parent/Child and some anchors and margins..

Comment: From DevX, you could try out https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/5368/Controls-and-Libraries/Docking-Library or https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/3406/Controls-and-Libraries/Form-Layout-Managers/Layout-and-Data-Layout-Controls, and https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/11359/Controls-and-Libraries/Application-UI-Manager - they all seem to be able to do something like what you want.